# Image Gallery alignment issue

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me with the following image gallery ? [image]

I am trying to align all items inside a container with width 940px and the gallery div is 740 but I cannot figure out the technique and do it properly. May I ask some of you who are more experienced to explain to me how to structure the code and do it in proper way ?

Here is my code until this moment but almost everything is broken...

```css
.container {  position: relative;  width: 940px; margin: 0 auto; }
.main { background: #f1f1e6; position: relative; }
.sidebar { display: block; width: 182px; float: left; padding: 41px 10px 10px 19px; }
.content { background: #fff; float: left; max-width: 740px; margin-top: 21px; overflow: hidden; box-shadow: 0 0 10px #99997a; }
.cf-me { clear: both; }

/* Content CSS Styles */

.sort-container { position: relative; left: 42.5%; }
.sort-items { position: relative; float: left; margin-top: 52px;  }
.sort-items p { float: left; padding: 0 4px; }
.filter-products { position: absolute; left: 100%; font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; color: #666651; background: #f2f2e7; border: 1px solid #e6e6cf; border-radius: 1px; padding: 2px 0; width: 160px; }

.product-label { display: block; float: left;  }
.product-label h1 { position: relative; font-family: "Arial", sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding: 15px 10px 16px 20px; }
.product-label h1:after { content:''; position: absolute; top: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6cf;  } 
.product-label p { padding: 0 5px 15px 20px; }

.product-list { clear: both; }
.product-list ul { margin-right: -240px; }
.product-list ul li { list-style: none; float: left; width: 144px; margin: 0 48px 7px 50px; }
.product-list ul li img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
.product-list ul li a { color: #fff; }
.product-list ul li a:hover { opacity: 0.8; }

.btn { background: url(../images/btn-image.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; }
.add-to-cart { font-family: "Arial", sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; padding: 9px 33px 10px 9px; }

.left-arrow { float: left; width: 24px; height: 126px; }
.left-arrow a { display: block; height: 100%; background: url(../images/arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; font-style: normal; overflow: hidden; text-indent: -100%; }
```

```html
 <main class="main">
 <div class="paper-border"></div>
  <div class="container">
   <aside class="sidebar">
    
   </aside><!-- sidebar -->
   <div class="content">
    <div class="product-label">
     <h1>Products > Category Page</h1>
     <p>Displaying 1-12 of 30 Product(s)</p>
    </div><!-- product-label -->
    <div class="sort-container">
     <div class="sort-items">
      <p>Sort By:</p>
      <select class="filter-products">
       <option value="default" selected>Default</option>
       <option value="product_1">Product 1</option>
       <option value="product_2">Product 2</option>
       <option value="product_3">Product 3</option>
      </select><!-- filter-products -->
     </div><!-- sort-items -->
    </div>
    <div class="product-list">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <div class="left-arrow">
        <a href="#">left arrow</a>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_1.jpg" width="110" height="121" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_2.jpg" width="138" height="87" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_3.jpg" width="139" height="87" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_4.jpg" width="160" height="160" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="left-arrow">
        <a href="#">left arrow</a>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_5.jpg" width="123" height="136" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_6.jpg" width="114" height="138" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_7.jpg" width="127" height="133" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_8.jpg" width="123" height="135" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title"Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li class="cf-me">
       <div class="left-arrow">
        <a href="#">left arrow</a>
       </div>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_9.jpg" width="142" height="135" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_10.jpg" width="75" height="140" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_11.jpg" width="75" height="129" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
      <li>
       <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="image"><img src="images/product_12.jpg" width="136" height="122" title="someText" alt="someText"></a>
        <p class="title">Product Title<br>Placeholder</p>
        <!-- /.title -->
        <p class="price">&dollar;99.99</p><!-- /.price -->
        <a href="#" class="btn add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>
       </div><!-- /.item -->
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div><!-- content -->
  </div><!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the gallery content to expand out to the 940px size you'll need to update the following line of code to `max-width: 940px`:

- `.content { background: #fff; float: left; max-width: 740px; margin-top: 21px; overflow: hidden; box-shadow: 0 0 10px #99997a; }`

That will only resolve the size issue a bit though. At that point you'll have margin issues and a breakdown of elements based on your tags `floats` and the `widths` that the code defines for each `DIV`

I did some light tinkering of your code and added in some images from [placehold.it](http://placehold.it) to try and see if I got what you're looking for. Take a look at the link below and let me know.

- https://jsfiddle.net/jdcutter/cwmf6fab/

Comment: Thank you for pointing out I'am going to learn the way you showed me ! Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem. If there is more you're looking to do to this layout feel free and ask for help. If not and this solves your problem, make sure to check mark the question so it filters into the completed section in the community. You can always direct message me if you have further questions later.